# How to set the width within axis label in highcharts

Tags: highcharts, bar-chart

Do anyone know which setting in hightcharts can change the width that marked with red arrow as example?

Please take a look at the image below

[I want to set the width of the red arrow as example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MgVaW.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using categories, so axis is divided evenly between all existing categories. In other words, you can simply remove unnecessary categories, for example: http://jsfiddle.net/mwqto4n6/

```
$('#container').highcharts({
    xAxis: {
         categories: ["2016", "2025"]
    },
    series: [{
        type: 'column',
        data: [200, 120]
    }]
});
```

Comment: ummmm... i think all of the cate are needed, is there any direct way to control the width between each label?

Comment: As I said above: `You are using categories, so axis is divided evenly between all existing categories.` You can not set for example 100px for first category and 50px for all others, sorry.

Comment: Is there any way to do it if i don't use categories ?

Comment: It depends how this chart should look like. Do you have a mockup? Just to be clear - you can not set something like "year 2015" -> 200px, "year 2014" -> 100px etc.